# differentiable function proofs

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

Im not sure if this appeared somewhere before but
$f$ is a differentiable function and if $\lim_\limits{x\to \infty}f'(x)=l$ how to show that $\lim_\limits{x\to \infty} \frac {f(x)}{x} = l$ ? 
Basically I used MVT and got stuck.. any clues? I think I need to work on this based on the epsilon definition of limits and combine it with the MVT.

Comment: Isn't that just L'Hospital?

Comment: If you know that the second limit exists, then yes.

Comment: The existence of $\lim_\limits{x\to \infty} \frac{f'(x)}{1}=l$ (together with $\lim_\limits{x\to \infty}  x = \infty$) implies that $\lim_\limits{x\to \infty} \frac {f(x)}{x} = l$.

Comment: @Martin R Well, that is the exercise...

Comment: L'Hopital works on $f/g$ if we only know $g(x)\to \infty.$ We don't need to assume anything about $f$ except differentiability

Comment: @zhw. Concerning integrability of $f'$: Due to what is given, we know that $f'$ is bounded. So, $f$ is absolutely continuous on bounded intervals. Thus, $f'$ is Lebesgue integrable on such.

Comment: I was referring to the Riemann integral. The Lebesgue integral seems like overkill on a problem like this.

Comment: Yes, I agree...

Answer (score 1):

Let $\varepsilon > 0$. Then there exists $x_0$ such that $|f'(t) - l| < \varepsilon/2$ for $t\ge x_0$. Now, for each $x > x_0$ there exists $t_x\in (x_0,x)$ such that $f(x) = f(x_0) + f'(t_x)(x-x_0)$. Hence,
$$
\frac{f(x)}x - l = \frac 1 x\left(f(x_0) - x_0f'(t_x)\right) + (f'(t_x) - l).
$$
Now, since $f'$ is bounded on $[x_0,\infty)$, there exists $x_1\ge x_0$ such that $\frac 1 x\left|f(x_0) - x_0f'(t_x)\right| < \frac{\varepsilon}2$ for $x > x_1$. So, applying the absolute value to the above line yields that $|\frac{f(x)}x - l| < \varepsilon$ for $x > x_1$. But that means $f(x)/x\to l$ as $x\to\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

For any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $x_1 > 0$ such that for $x > x_1$ we have $l - \epsilon <f'(x) < l + \epsilon.$

By the mean value theorem there exists $\xi$ between $x_1$ and $x$ such that

$$l - \epsilon < \frac{f(x)-f(x_1)}{x - x_1} = f'(\xi) < l + \epsilon.$$

Hence

$$l - \epsilon < \frac{\frac{f(x)}{x}-\frac{f(x_1)}{x}}{1 - \frac{x_1}{x}} < l + \epsilon.$$

Since $f(x_1)/x \to 0$ and $x_1/x \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$ we have

$$l - \epsilon < \liminf_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{x} \leqslant  \limsup_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{x} < l + \epsilon.$$

Since $\epsilon > 0$ can be arbitrarily small it follows that

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{x} = l.$$